# How many of Dr Gero's Androids were actually Androids and how many were Cyborgs?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

We know that Androids 17 and 18 were in fact humans who were enhanced making them Cyborgs rather than Androids (as evident by at least 18 after the Cell Saga) and Dr Gero himself had his own brain in his Android Body which makes him a Cyborg because he is still part biological.

Out of all of the Androids Dr Gero created how many of them were actually Androids and how many of the were Cyborgs?

Answer (score 4):

I only listed the ones which are in the canon or in the movies. I haven't listed the ones in the games.

**Android #1-#7**: Considered failures and destroyed. We don't know much about about them.

**Android #8**: According to some guides, it (he?) is a cyborg. But let's consider him a fully artificial android because it's not stated in the canon anywhere (I guess).

**Android #9-#12**: Same as 1-7, destroyed.

**Android #13-#15**: Non-canon android appearing in "Super Android 13!". May be fully android considering their construction was started before 16, 17 and 18.

**Android #16**: Pure android.

**Android #17-#18**: Everybody knows them. They are cyborgs.

**Android #19**: Pure robot.

**Android #20**: Dr. Gero himself. He is a cyborg as you said.

So to answer your question, out of 20 androids made by Dr. Gero, only 3 are cyborgs and the rest are fully android.

I've used the android term as a replacement for robot. But android literally means cyborg.

I guess this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

My list detailing my enterpretation of what Doctor Gero's creations actually are...

Cyborg 8

Android 13

Android 14

Android 15

Android 16

Semi-Artificial Cyborg 17

Semi-Artificial Cyborg 18

Artificial Cyborg 19

Cyborg 20 (Doctor Gero)

Imperfect Cell (semi-artificial cyborg clone)

Semi-Artificial Human 17 (Lapis, bomb removal)

Semi-Artificial Human 18 (Lazuli, bomb removal)